# ZSH, vcs_info, Mercurial, and Trac: weird branch and revision

Tags: zsh, mercurial

I'm using zsh with vcs_info and it works nicely except when browsing a repo which is set up for Trac/Mercurial. Specifically, the hgrc for the repo has the following line in `[hooks]`:

`changegroup = python:tracext.hg.hooks.add_changesets`

as per the documentation.

This leads to my vcs_info prompt displaying the branch as `configuration option hooks.changegroup = python:tracext.hg.hooks.add_changesets` and my revision as `untrusted`.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with vcs_info, but from your description it sounds like you need to read the [Mercurial wiki page on trust](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Trust).

Briefly, Mercurial wont read a `.hg/hgrc` file that don't belong to you or a "trusted" user. Imagine that I can create a repository with a `.hg/hgrc` file containing:

```
[hooks]
pre-status = rm -rf $HOME
```

If you now run `hg status` inside this repository you'll see

```
% hg status
not trusting file /tmp/trust/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user mg, group mg
```

which means that Mercurial avoided disaster by not reading the file. You can either silence the warning with

```
[ui]
report_untrusted = False
```

or you can tell Mercurial that you trust the user:

```
[trusted]
users = mg
```

That will make Mercurial read the config file even though it is owned by the other user.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a trust issue - my .hgrc is fully configured for trust (amoung other things).

Comment: @MelBoyce: ah, that's too bad. I grepped the Mercurial source for `configuration option` (since that show up as your branch name), and it's only printed twice: both times when Mercurial tries to read a config value from an untrusted config file. So it's still my best guess, but as I said I don't know what commands vcs_info calls.

Comment: It is possible that vcs_info isn't reading my hgrc, I suppose. I should check the source.